# Multi Site Manager On Multiple Servers

Tags: multi-site-manager, server

The user guide for the multi site manager states that one requirement is that all sites must reside on the same server. I was wondering if anyone could please explain why this is the case?

I need to possibly setup multiple instances of the same EE installation on different servers using the same domain and connecting to the same database. However, the EE installation I have uses multi site manager, which leads me to believe that this will not be possible.

Any clarification anyone can provide on this will be much appreciated.

Comment: this is the legal question. Not the technical. You need to discuss it with EllisLab.

Comment: Legal issues aside, there are technical problems as well. I'm sure with enough hackery it could be done, but I doubt it'd work well.

Answer (score 1):

The index.php and admin.php files in each site's document root references the shared system directory for all the sites. So, if the sites were on different servers you wouldn't be able to access the system folder path which lies on another server.

Comment: Bingo! This nails it.